# Two instances of the theme folder in the URL

Tags: theme-development, url-rewriting

I realized that two instances of the theme folder show up in the URL. For example, this is how it looks: /wp-content/themes/**tempus/tempus**/archive.php.

I'm not sure if I did this by accident when installing or if the theme developer did this on purpose for some reason. I tried simply moving the contents of the second 'tempus' folder into the first, but I should have known it wouldn't be so easy. I got an error saying the stylesheet was missing.

Is there a simple way to fix this and consolidate the two folders into one?

Comment: It might not be the way you thought. Some themes use subfolders for individual php files, such as `single.php` or `sidebar.php`. The theme's root is `/tempus/` and the stylesheet is expected to be found at `/wp-content/tempus/style.css`. Although this is a guess, since there is not enough information in your question to post an accurate answer.

Comment: @Jack Thank you. I know that the stylesheet is expected to be at `/wp-content/tempus/style.css` but there is no stylesheet there. Only the second 'tempus' folder which holds the stylesheet.

Comment: you are welcome. But you mentioned that you have moved the second folder to `/wp-content/`. So, when do you receive the error? Before or after the movement?

Comment: ^Sorry, I mistyped in my last message. I forgot the `theme` folder in between `wp-content` and `tempus`. Also, sorry for the misunderstanding. I moved the second tempus folder's contents into the first tempus folder but it produced the error and the site wouldn't load, so I moved the second folder's contents back for now.

Comment: The safest thing to do: download a fresh copy of the theme, delete the old, upload the new version. As long as you do this in FTP and don't deactivate the theme, your settings should all be preserved. If that's not possible, look in your file backups and do the same.